# Springboot and KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, keycloak

I'm trying to plug in Keycloak authentication in my web application on Springboot with KeycloakAdapter. But when i trying to login from application homepage, i get 401 error. Logfile contains this error:

```
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.k.a.s.f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Request is to process authentication
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.k.a.s.f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Attempting Keycloak authentication
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters - Set encoding to UTF-8
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator - NOT_ATTEMPTED: bearer only
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.k.a.s.f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Auth outcome: NOT_ATTEMPTED
2021-10-05 18:34:39,839 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9090-exec-3] DEBUG o.k.a.s.f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter - Authentication request failed: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Authorization header not found,  see WWW-Authenticate header
org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Authorization header not found,  see WWW-Authenticate header
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

I think i need to get authorization token from Keycloak and call login endpoint with it, but i cant understand where and how to do this. And its starange, that i need authenticate before authenticate... Seems like I do something wrong. Colleagues, who integarates Keycloak with Springboot, give me a hand with this please.

My config:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = {KeycloakSecurityComponents.class},
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(WEBJARS_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(DEVICE_API_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(NON_TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINTS).permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(WS_TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated()
                .antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

And .yml

```
keycloak:
  realm: "myRealm"
  auth-server-url: "http://localhost:18080/auth"
  ssl-required: "external"
  resource: "myResource"
  credentials:
    secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  use-resource-role-mappings: "true"
  bearer-only: "true"
```

Comment: For login I call /sso/login

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It works if change parameter `bearer-only` to `false` in .yml

```
keycloak:
  realm: "myRealm"
  auth-server-url: "http://localhost:18080/auth"
  ssl-required: "external"
  resource: "myResource"
  credentials:
    secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  use-resource-role-mappings: "true"
  bearer-only: "false"
```